# Does jScrollPane require all text content to be placed within <p> tags to render properly?

Tags: html, jscrollpane

I'm using

jScrollPane
// *Version: 2.0.0beta11, Last updated: 2011-07-04*

and finding that:

```
<div class="scroll-pane">
line 1<br />line 2<br />line 3<br />line 4
</div>
```

is rendered as a single line. i.e line breaks are stripped out,  and the vertical scroll bar is then placed below the content. However if i wrap the content in p tags:

```
  <div class="scroll-pane"><p>
     line 1<br />line 2<br />line 3<br />line 4<p>
    </div>
```

then the content is rendered as expected, as 4 individual lines with a verticle scrollbar.

Is this a known issue? A bug? Or just how it should due to HTML rule re:validity?

Answer (score 6):

In the meanwhile, there is a workaround to fix this issue by replacing how plugin retrieves data from containing div. Check [br tags within a jScrollPane seem to get lost?](https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues/49)